# Adding new line on a one2many computed field with inverse odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I have a one2many computed field which i also want users to be able to add new line of records into. i added an inverse field to it, but the only thing it does is to allow already existing records to be modified

```
@api.one
def accumulate_files(self):
    documents = self.env['document.customer']
    document_gotten = documents.search([('name','=', self.name)])
    for docs in document_gotten:
        self.res_line_ids |= docs.customer_line_ids

@api.one      
def edit_accumulate_files(self):
    documents = self.env['document.customer']
    for lines in documents.customer_line_ids:
        lines.write(self.res_line_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround, not sure how can I get values of one2many field in inverse method, in new api, like it was in old api. however it works for me

```
    @api.multi
    def _save_telefone(self):
        for partner in self:
            for phone in partner.phone_number_ids:
                try:
                    # write on exisiting record
                    int(phone.id)
                    # write all possible values
                    phone.write({'partner_id': partner.id})

                except:
                    # create new record with all possible values
                    phone.create({
                        'partner_id': partner.id,
                        'type_id': phone.type_id.id,
                        'status_id': phone.status_id.id,
                        'sequence': phone.sequence,
                        'graph_value': phone.graph_value,
                        'name': phone.name,
                    })

            return True
```

> Basically, create a record if it doesn't exist otherwise write on it.
>   how to know if record exists in DB? if the ID is integer it already
>   exists, otherwise it will have ID something like "odoo.model.NewID"
>   that means ID hasn't been assigned yet record is in memory yet.